# Write a program to remove the whitespaces from a given string

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have solved the related question with o(n) time complexity and o(n) space complexity approach as follows; but the interviewed wanted o(n) time complexity with constant space complexity. How can I solve it with constant space complexity?

```
public static StringBuilder removeWhiteSpaces (String str){

    if (str == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length(); i++){
        if (str.charAt(i) != ' '){
        result.append(str.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: You can't. Strings are **immutable**, so you *must* create a new String to return a stripped value. At the very least, that means a new `char[]`, and a new `String` (which copies the `char[]`), **unless** you're allowed to receive the "string" as a `char[]` and can update it in-place, returning the new length.

Comment: @Andreas theoretically you could use reflection, to get and modify `String` inner field `value` but I think it is overkill for interview

Comment: Hi could someone please provide me with a link, as to where I can learn more about complexities, thanks.

Comment: @RamanSB You mean like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation?

Comment: @Andreas something less wordy and more tutorial based

Comment: @user902383 **Heck no!** Never try a stunt like that. You might *corrupt* the interned string pool.

Comment: @RamanSB Google it: [`O(n)`](https://www.google.com/search?q=O%28n%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: @Andreas I know that, and I'm not recommending that. I'm only saying it is possible with reflection.

Comment: @user902383 Too many n00bs on here. Don't ever suggest stuff like that, as a joke or whatever the intention was, because someone might actually think it's a viable option. *It is not*

Comment: @Andreas you were once a noob

Comment: @Andreas I'm sorry, I want do this again:)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Java, but I do remember that `String` is immutable. What you ask is impossible to do when the string to strip is stored inside `String`. This is because we can't modify the input, and we need memory to store the result.

---

However, if you can store the string in mutable memory (e.g. `char[]` or `StringBuilder`), you can use the following algorithm. Keep two indices, `r` and `w` and initialize them to 0. Loop over the string using `r`, incrementing it for every character you read. Then if that character is not whitespace, write it to `w` and increment it.

When finished discard the last `r - w` characters of the string.

Example in C:

```
void remove_whitespace(char* s) {
    char* r = s;
    char* w = s;

    while (*r) {
        if (!std::isspace(*r)) *w++ = *r;
        ++r;
    }

    *w = 0;
}
```

Comment: Exactly my thought!
It is possible but not in Java!
You can't change a String. Therefore you need new space where you can write the results.

Comment: probably after the using two indices, without removing the elements, I needed to print it in a original string from 0 to index w.

Comment: Well, apply [.toCharArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--) and you can work with the array of characters.

Comment: Down-vote: Not Java, can't do pointer logic. So "not useful".

Comment: @Andreas I explained the algorithm __without pointer logic__, _then_ added the C code only as an example. I think the downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: Question is "from a given string". Your logic doesn't work on immutable `String`, which, granted, you did mention, but it still makes the answer not useful.

Comment: @Andreas By your definition no answer to this question can be useful, because it's impossible to the strict definition of the asker. I'd argue that my answer is useful, because it shows an algorithm that can work under relaxed type requirements.

Comment: A "useful" answer will actually answer the question up front, not hide it at the end. A great answer may list alternatives. If you like, you can reformat the answer, and I would find it very useful and remove down-vote. With answer delegated to a note at the end, my down-vote stays.

Comment: Down-vote removed. *FYI:* You can't "discard" remaining characters, not even in C tho you can terminate it in C, but in Java you *can* return new length.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 good ways to improve your answer in Java:

1) There are other whitespace characters besides ' ', and you have to check for them all.  Use Character.isWhitespace() or (if you're old like me) <= ' '.

2) You should hold off on making the StringBuilder until you actually see a whitespace character.  If you get to the end without one, just return the original string.

Most people in Java would do this with a regex search and replace, but if you have to write a utility function for it, it's better to do it this way (after these improvements), because it will be more efficient.

If the interviewer then asks you for constant space, then the best response is to explain that strings are immutable in Java, so you will have to make an overload of the method that takes a StringBuilder argument that it will then modify.  There are ways to do this in other popular languages like C++ and C (orlp's answer), but they are all equivalent to taking a mutable StringBuilder, so there's no need to switch languages.

Comment: Alternate to `StringBuilder`: Accept `char[]`, modify it and return new length.

Answer (score 0):

Was the question in the interview "from a given String" (literally meaning you had to use `String str` as input), or did you just assume you had to use a String object instead of e.g. a `char[]` or `StringBuilder`.

With `String` it wouldn't work. As soon as you use something like `str.toCharArray()`, you would allocate new memory of at least the same length as `str`. And you can't modify the characters in `str`, as was already mentioned several times.